# How to align two divs in one row inside Appbar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I want the whole `Container` in one row and the `Typography` in the center (which already is) and the `toggle-container` to float right

```
    <AppBar className={styles.AppBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Container>
          <div>
          <Typography align='center' variant="h5">
          COVID-19 Información
          </Typography>
          </div>
          <div className="toggle-container">
          <span style={{ color: darkMode ? "grey" : "yellow" }}>☀︎</span>
          <span className="toggle">
            <input
              checked={darkMode}
              onChange={() => setDarkMode(prevMode => !prevMode)}
              id="checkbox"
              className="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
            />
            <label htmlFor="checkbox" />
          </span>
          <span style={{ color: darkMode ? "slateblue" : "grey" }}>☾</span>
          </div>
          </Container>
        </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
```

```
.AppBar{
    background-color: rgb(247, 171, 6) !important;
    background-image: url('...'),url('...');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain ,10%;
    background-position-x: 62%,30%;
}

 .toggle {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 4px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

.toggle-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    float: right;
  }
  
  .toggle-container > span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"].checkbox {
    width: 40px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #555;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: 2px;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"].checkbox:checked + label {
    left: 30px;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"].checkbox:focus-visible {
    outline: solid 2px white;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"].checkbox + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: cyan;
  }
```

Comment: So what is the specific problem? We have no idea what your CSS looks like currently or what is actually happening. See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl well do whatever with the CSS, if you are not familiar with Material UI, the `Appbar` is like a navbar of a normal HTML, I want the `Typography` (i.e. title) in the middle of the `Appbar` and  the `toggle-container` in the rightmost of the containe.And the whole `Appbar` in one line/row

Comment: Fine but you have not provided a specific problem with what you currently have which is the whole point of my comment. Instead it sounds like you expect others to produce the needed code without showing what you have tried. That is not how SO works. It is expected that you show your own attempts to solve your issue and others help when they don't work properly

Comment: well I tried and I have the code and not working the way I want , I know the people who know Material UI will know what to do

Comment: So the point is show what you tried. Will get you a lot more respect when asking questions here as it is expected

Comment: @charlietfl wait i am adding the css

Comment: Great...then it can become a [mcve] that we can run and debug

Comment: @charlietfl check it

Comment: There you go...even better if there was actual html that anyone can run without your React code

Comment: @charlietfl see the below sandbox in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style your `Container` with:

```css
display: flex;
align-items: center
```

and the parent element of the `Typography` component with:

```css
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Here is a working example:

[image: Edit nervous-curie-nlvp2]

Comment: @KALITA I provided a complete example based on your code.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am talking about , the theme toggle button stays on the bottom but i want that in a same row with the title

Comment: @KALITA reload the Codesandbox page again. There was an issue I just resolved; it should work now as desired.
If you see an error message that AppBar couldn't be resolved, just reload the page - seems to be a bug with Codesandbox.

Comment: thanks a lot , it's 3 am here now i can sleep peacefully